# Why do x+x and !(x+x) appear to have the same value when x=(int)0x80000000?

Tags: c, gcc, overflow

I wrote the following code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x = 0x80000000;
    printf("x+x = %d; !(x+x) = %d\n",x+x,!(x+x));
    return 0;
}
```

and compile by gcc 11.3.0 in both WSL2(Ubuntu) and Debian x86_64

but the answer is

```
x+x = 0; !(x+x) = 0
```

Could anyone explain what happened in `!` to get the wrong answer? Thanks very much.

I've tried on different machines but the answer is the same. Or maybe overflow causes flag change which effects `!`?  I wonder the answer...

Comment: Your code is using signed `int` overflow on a system where `sizeof(int) == 4` (most systems these days).  That's undefined behaviour.  Your title talks about `!(0)=0`, but your code is using `!(x+x)` — which is quite different.  Please make the title and the question consistent.

Comment: The title is still not correct. In `0x80000000+0x80000000`, `0x80000000` would have the type `unsigned`, and `0x80000000+0x80000000` would be fully defined to wrap and produce zero. A better title might be “Why do x+x and !(x+x) appear to have the same value?”

Comment: thanks for your precise description! edited.

Answer (score 4):

> `int x = 0x80000000;`

`0x80000000` has the value 2<sup>31</sup>. Assuming `int` is 32 bits in your C implementation, this is not representable in `int`. An implementation-defined conversion is performed. [GCC defines the conversion to wrap](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.3.0/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation), so the result is −2<sup>31</sup>.

> `printf("x+x = %d; !(x+x) = %d\n",x+x,!(x+x));`

Since `x` is −2<sup>31</sup>, `x+x` overflows the `int` type. Then the behavior of the program is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: For this reason, MSVC has `#define INT_MIN (-2147483647 - 1)` and not `-2147483648`.